# Автогенерация поля при создании экземпляра модели Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Есть модель `ShareLink`, в ней есть поле `qrcode_image` с типом `ImageField`. Я хочу, чтобы при создании экземпляра данной модели генерировалось изображение QR-кода и сохранялось в данном поле. Как такое реализовать?

Исходник модели `ShareLink`:

```
class ShareLink(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=False)
    qrcode_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='account/share_link/qr_code/')
    schedules = models.TextField(blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='sharelinks_used', blank=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        str = 'ShareLink: id: {}, slug: {}'.format(self.id, self.slug)
        return str
```

---

Данный исходник генерирует QR-код, и получает изображение:

```
import qrcode

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=6,
        border=0,
    )

# Добавляет данные в QR и получает изображение
qr.add_data('ta.taranets')
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image()
```

Как действовать дальше: как сохранять данное изображение по правильному пути и добавить в `qrcode_image`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете переопределить метод `save`, генерируя в нём это поле.

***Пример:***

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


class ShareLink(models.Model):
    qrcode_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='account/share_link/qr_code/')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img_name = ...
        img_content = ...
        self.qrcode_image.save(img_name, ContentFile(img_content))
        super(ShareLink, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Сделал след. изменение в коде: `img = qr.make_image()` и `self.qrcode_image = img` в методе save. Вышла ошибка: `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'`

Comment: @Георгий Вы передаёте само изображение в это поле? Если так, то Вам необходимо до этого обернуть его в специальный класс. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49296707/11558617) на английском StackOverflow.

Comment: @Георгий Я обновил ответ, добавив пример обёртки на основе [`ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class). Можно использовать и другие обёртки.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Все заработало!

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться сигналами [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) или [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save).

С помощью сигнала `post_save` можно дополнительно получить информацию о том, был ли создан экземпляр (или существовал ранее) и какие поля в нём были изменены (если он не был только что создан).

***Пример:***

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


@receiver(post_save, sender=ShareLink)
def generate_qrcode(sender, instance, created, update_fields, **kwargs):
    img_name = ...
    img_content = ...
    instance.qrcode_image.save(img_name, ContentFile(img_content))
    instance.save()
```